# How to loop a range with python

Tags: python

This is my question:
I have to write a function that accepts 2 integer values as parameters and returns the sum of all the integers between the two values, including the first and last values. The parameters may be in any order (i.e. the second parameter may be smaller than the first).

This is the example of the result:

[image: screenshot]

This is what I've tried:

```
def sum_range(int1,int2):
    count = 0
    for i in range(int1,int2+1):
         count = count + i
    return count
```

but for this example:

```
result = sum_range(3, 2)

print(result)
```

I got the wrong result, can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to swap your variables if `int2` is smaller than `int1`:

```
def sum_range(int1, int2):
    if int1 > int2:
        int2, int1 = int1, int2
    count = 0
    for i in range(int1, int2 + 1):
         count = count + i
    return count
```

You don't really need to use a loop here, if you passed your `range()` to the [`sum()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), then you can leave the looping and summing to that function:

```
def sum_range(int1, int2):
    if int1 > int2:
        int2, int1 = int1, int2
    return sum(range(int1, int2 + 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using loops:

```
def sum_range(num1, num2):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(min(num1, num2), max(num1, num2) + 1):
        sum += i
    return sum
```

Note: You could also do:

```
def sum_range(num1, num2):
    return abs((num1 * (num1 + 1) / 2) - (num2 * (num + 1) / 2))
## This works as you're essentially asking for the difference between two triangular numbers
```

Comment: Code only answers are not as helpful as those which explain: 1) Why the OPs code doesn't work and 2) Why yours does.

Comment: or `return abs((num1 * (num1 + 1) // 2) - (num2 * (num2 + 1) // 2))`

Answer (score 0):

`range` counts from the first parameter *up to* (but not including) the second, which means the range is *empty* if the first is no smaller than the second.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use the loop:

```
def sum_range(int1, int2):
    if int1 > int2:
        int2, int1 = int1, int2
    return sum(list(range(int1,int2+1)))
```

**Example:**

```
result = sum_range(4, 2)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
9
```